# Expected number of tosses to get 2 heads in a row - what is wrong with my approach?

Tags: probability

The problem is to find the expected number of tosses required to get 2 heads in a row of an unfair coin with probability $p$ that it is head.

The way I thought about this problem is, given 2 tosses, we have the following possibilities with their probability of occuring in parenthesis:

$$
HH \ \ (p^2) \\
TH \ \ (p-p^2)\\
HT \ \ (p-p^2)\\
TT \ \ (1-p)^2
$$

Let $N$ be the random variable for number of tosses to get 2 heads in a row, and $M$ be the random variable for number of tosses to get 1 head. We can now compute its expectation. There are 4 possible scenarios we could ran into that are enumerated above. For the first scenario, $HH$, this requires 2 moves. For the second scenario, $TH$, We need 1 more head, so we add 1 more move and the expected number of moves to get a head, giving us $(1+E[M])$. For $HT$ and $TT$, both cases end in tail, so we need to seek 2 more heads in a row, giving us $(2 + E[N]).

$$
    E[N] = 2*p^2 + (p - p^2)*(1 + E[M]) + (p-p^2)*(2 + E[N])+ (1-p)^2*(2+E[N]) \\
    E[M] = p*1 + (1-p)(1+E[M]) \\
    \implies E[m] = \frac{1}{p} \\
    E[N] = 2p^2 + (1-p)(2+E[N]) + (p-p^2)(1+\frac{1}{p}) \\
    E[N] = \frac{p^2-2p+3}{p} \\
$$

The solution is $E[N] = \frac{1+p}{p^2}$.

I can't figure out what is wrong with my approach. Any ideas?

I understand there are other approaches, but I first want to understand what is wrong with my thinking.

Comment: I really can't follow your approach.  I think you are trying to do it with states.  If so, we have two states according to whether the last toss was $H$ or non-$H$ (counting the "last toss" before you start as a non-$H$, and of course we have the END state.  Thus you have $E_{\emptyset}$ and $E_H$ to consider.  Easy to work out simple relations between these.

Comment: Can you write out how you got the equation for $ E[N]$? In particular, for the $TH$ case, are you sure the number of rolls that we need to get a $HH$ is just $2 + E[N]$? What if we got a $H$ in the third roll?

Comment: @CalvinLin. I edited the equation for E[N], I had the HT and TH's order swapped in the E[N] equation earlier.

Comment: Same criticism applies. Consider the $TH$ case. __Hint:__ For the value is $2 + E[M]$, is that for "see exactly 2 heads in the sequence" or "see 2 heads consecutively in the sequence"?

Comment: Do you mean $1+E[M]$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with $TH$ you are multiplying by $1+E[M]$, presumably because you are considering the tail wasted and thinking you already have the first head.  If you next throw a tail, the first head is wasted as well. You should multiply by $3p+(1-p)(3+E[N])$ because if you start with $TH$ you succeed in $3$ tosses with probability $p$ and with probability $1-p$ you get tails and are back at start with $3$ wasted tosses.

Comment: Hmm I'm not following the explanation of $3p + (1-p)(3+E[N])$. Would you be able to rephrase it?

Comment: If your third toss is tails (probability $1-p$) you have no heads in a row, so need to throw two in succession.  That takes on average $E[N]$ tosses.  The $E[M]$ approach would only apply if you were looking for a total of two heads, regardless of whether a tail came between them.  It would then apply to starting with $HT$ as well.

Comment: So I think I now understand where the $(1-p)(3+E[N])$ comes from. In my own words, it's, starting from $TH$, and consider that the next flip results in a $T$ (i.e., we now have the sequence $THT$), then we will have wasted 3 flips (the $THT$), and then must recurse again on $E[N]$. Is this the right idea? Could you also please rephrase how the $3p$ came about, which I believe corresponds to the sequence $THH$?

Comment: The 3p comes from starting with THH, when you have your two heads after three tosses.  You already had the factor $p(1-p)$ for the first two.

Comment: Did you do some simplifications in your head to get the $3p$. Sorry, I'm still not seeing how the $3p$ came about after starting with THH.

Comment: Ah I think I got it. I just realized how weird it was for me to understand the $(1-p)(3+E[N])$ part but not the $3p$ part.  

Is 3+(1−)(3+[]) in itself an expected value?